# Wordpress => Is a PHP function can EDIT (no matter what) and CLICK on "Publish" for all posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

Creating a function to:

1) Do something in post editor (Wordpress)

2) Once the action done, Click on "Publish" button

Note => I'm able to import this function (PHP or javascript) at the creation of the posts (because my posts are imported...)

Comment: Unclear question. Please revise.

Comment: I can provide the CSS selector but I'm not sure it will improve my question. I need help to ask the good question because I don't get it

Comment: I have reworded my question. Providing code here is no-sense because I don't even know which language I need => but I am 80% sure that PHP can do that

Comment: Your question is still unclear and not answerable… see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you mention some hooks like `publish_post` or `save_post`
Ex:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'custom-function' );

//Your function here
function custom-function() {
    //Some code
}
```

Comment: This is the answer to what I am asking, thanks Tony.
For further, my custom action is:

1) Click on a tab (CSS Selector):
#plugin > ul > li:nth-child(1)

2) Select the 1st checkbox (CSS Selector):
#customtab > input(1)

I'm reading documentation https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/